# Faster method to multiply column lookup values with vectorization

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two Dataframes, one contains values and is the working dataset (postsolutionDF), while the other is simply for reference as a lookup table (factorimportpcntDF). The goal is to add a column to postsolutionDF that contains the product of the lookup values from each row of postsolutionDF (new column name = num_predict). That product is then multiplied by 2700. For example, on first row, the working values are 0.5, 2, -6. The equivalent lookup values for these are 0.1182, 0.2098, and 0.8455. The product of those is 0.0209, which when multiplied by 2700 is 56.61 as shown in output.

The code below works for this simplified example, but it is very slow in the real solution (1.6MM rows x 15 numbered columns). I'm sure there is a better way to do this by removing the 'for k in range' loop but am struggling with how since already using apply on rows. I've found many tangential solutions but nothing that has worked for my situation yet. Thanks for any help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

postsolutionDF = pd.DataFrame({'SCRN' : (['2019-01-22-0000001', '2019-01-22-0000002', '2019-01-22-0000003']), '1' : 0.5,
                               '2' : 2, '3' : ([-6, 1.0, 8.0])})
postsolutionDF = postsolutionDF[['SCRN', '1', '2', '3']]
print('printing initial postsolutionDF..')
print(postsolutionDF)

factorimportpcntDF = pd.DataFrame({'F1_Val' : [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2], 'F1_Pcnt' : [0.1182, 0.2938, 0.4371, 0.5433], 'F2_Val'
: [2, 3, np.nan, np.nan], 'F2_Pcnt' : [0.2098, 0.7585, np.nan, np.nan], 'F3_Val' : [-6, 1, 8, np.nan], 'F3_Pcnt' :
    [0.8455, 0.1753, 0.072, np.nan]})

print('printing factorimportpcntDF..')
print(factorimportpcntDF)

def zero_filter(row): # row is series
    inner_value = 1
    for k in range(1, 4): # number of columns in postsolutionDF with numeric headers, dynamic in actual code
        inner_value *= factorimportpcntDF.loc[factorimportpcntDF['F'+str(k)+'_Val']==row[0+k], 'F'+str(k)+'_Pcnt'].values[0]
    inner_value *= 2700
    return inner_value

postsolutionDF['num_predict'] = postsolutionDF.apply(zero_filter, axis=1)
print('printing new postsolutionDF..')
print(postsolutionDF)
```

Print Output:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/Eric/.PyCharmCE2017.3/config/scratches/scratch_5.py
printing initial postsolutionDF..
                 SCRN    1  2    3
0  2019-01-22-0000001  0.5  2 -6.0
1  2019-01-22-0000002  0.5  2  1.0
2  2019-01-22-0000003  0.5  2  8.0
printing factorimportpcntDF..
   F1_Pcnt  F1_Val  F2_Pcnt  F2_Val  F3_Pcnt  F3_Val
0   0.1182     0.5   0.2098     2.0   0.8455    -6.0
1   0.2938     1.0   0.7585     3.0   0.1753     1.0
2   0.4371     1.5      NaN     NaN   0.0720     8.0
3   0.5433     2.0      NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN
printing new postsolutionDF..
                 SCRN    1  2    3  num_predict
0  2019-01-22-0000001  0.5  2 -6.0    56.610936
1  2019-01-22-0000002  0.5  2  1.0    11.737312
2  2019-01-22-0000003  0.5  2  8.0     4.820801

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: can you explain row 2 , i understood row 1 reading your question, but not how to go with row 2

Comment: Do the indexes in both DFs correspond to one another? Thas is, is index 0 in `factorimportpcntDF` the lookup for index 0 in `postsolutionDF`? If they are, or if you have any other means to merge the dataframes into one, you can easily vectorize the computation. I can see that your DFs are of different length, with suggests that the indexes are not corresponding. Also, columns `["1", "2", "3"]` in `postsolutionDF` seem to match columns `["F1_Val", "F2_Val", "F3_Val"]` for the first row, but not for the other rows, which suggest we can't merge on those either.

Comment: The indexes are not corresponding. The postsolutionDF index goes up to around 1.6MM while the factorimportpcntDF index is static at the 4 rows shown. The colums in postsolutionDF do correspond to the columns in factorimportpcntDF. For example, column "1" in postsolutionDF will always correspond to lookup column "F1_Val" in factorimportpcntDF and resulting value column "F1_Pcnt" column in factorimportpcntDF. Effectively, you could create a lookup dict for each numbered column in postsolutionDF based on its "F1_Val" and "F1_Pcnt" columns in the factorimportpcntDF. Very important clarification!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this in native pandas, but if you go back to numpy, it is pretty easy.

The [numpy.interp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) function is designed to interpolate between values in the lookup table, but if the input values exactly match the values in the lookup table (like yours do), it becomes just a simple lookup instead of an interpolation.

```
postsolutionDF['1new'] = np.interp(postsolutionDF['1'].values, factorimportpcntDF['F1_Val'], factorimportpcntDF['F1_Pcnt'])
postsolutionDF['2new'] = np.interp(postsolutionDF['2'].values, factorimportpcntDF['F2_Val'], factorimportpcntDF['F2_Pcnt'])
postsolutionDF['3new'] = np.interp(postsolutionDF['3'].values, factorimportpcntDF['F3_Val'], factorimportpcntDF['F3_Pcnt'])
postsolutionDF['num_predict'] = postsolutionDF['1new'] * postsolutionDF['2new'] * postsolutionDF['3new'] * 2700
postsolutionDF.drop(columns=['1new', '2new', '3new'], inplace=True)
```

Gives the output:

```
In [167]: postsolutionDF
Out[167]: 
                 SCRN    1  2    3  num_predict
0  2019-01-22-0000001  0.5  2 -6.0    56.610936
1  2019-01-22-0000002  0.5  2  1.0    11.737312
2  2019-01-22-0000003  0.5  2  8.0     4.820801
```

I had to pad out the factorimportpcntDF so all the columns had 4 values, otherwise looking up the highest value for a column wouldn't work. You can just use the same value multiple times, or split it into 3 lookup tables if you prefer, then the columns could be different lengths.

```
factorimportpcntDF = pd.DataFrame({'F1_Val' : [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2], 'F1_Pcnt' : [0.1182, 0.2938, 0.4371, 0.5433],
'F2_Val' : [2, 3, 3, 3], 'F2_Pcnt' : [0.2098, 0.7585, 0.7585, 0.7585],
'F3_Val' : [-6, 1, 8, 8], 'F3_Pcnt' : [0.8455, 0.1753, 0.072, 0.072]})
```

Note that the documentation specifies that your `F1_val` etc columns need to be in increasing order (yours are here, just an FYI). Otherwise interp will run, but won't necessarily give good results.